# MS SQL advanced job scheduling for last working day

Tags: sql-server

Given a (for us) large datastream, of about 2GB/day. This data has to be incorporated/structured/cleansed into a destination database (this part is solved).

Until now we were dropping and creating a new datatable every day for the whole dataset of the current month, and then union into a materialized table of the previous months' dataset.

Besides, that this is a very un-elegant way, also unfortunately by the end of the month this query is becoming quite massive and draining the server for up to 1,5 hours daily.

I thought I do a parameterized query for date by grabbing all the data for DateMax 
(

```
declare @ReportDateMax datetime
set @ReportDateMax = dateadd(dd,-1, cast(getdate() as date)
```

)

however it is not good enough-
**the problem is the following:**
     1. on monday we need to download the data for friday
     2. on tuesday for monday
     3. wednesday for tuesday
     4. thursday for wednesday
     5. friday for thursday

which means that I cannot just download the information for yesterday, as than on monday I would not get anything.
Also ideally, if we just daily data I would like to run twice a day a select query for the previous reporting day.

**desired solution:**
design a query which selects the previous working day (public holidays are irrelevant for the topic).

Comment: (regardless the overall design) Populate `Calendar` table and utilize any information about all the days in it. `select top 1 ... where date < getdate and is_working_day = 1 order by date desc`

Comment: Why don't you run the job Saturday? The server is offline or you do it manually? or you can just run it and check the result on monday like you do now?

Comment: Adinugraha Tawaqal I cant run it on saturday, as there are corrections done with the data on monday morning

Comment: the correction is done during the job not after the job ?

Comment: Yes correction is done the following working day

Comment: Could You run the job on saturday and then do the correction on monday?

Comment: Corrections are made in the source system, and in a different business decision. Certainly would require more to dos than change an sql script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution eventually in another post.
In case somebody else is interested:

```
                    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                    ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```